# Перевод из object в int. Часть данных переводит , часть нет

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

При переводе из типа `object` в `int`  часть данных заменяется на `NaN`.

Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно?

Загружаю файл: выгрузка из 1С

```
df = pd.read_csv("333.csv", sep=';', header=0, index_col="СубконтоДт1")
df.dtypes
```

Все объекты (`object`).

В колонке `Сумма` объект присутствует.

[image: в колонке сумма есть]

Дальше удаляю пробелы, вставляю `NaN` и перевожу в формат `int`, и эти два столбца из  `object` стали `float`,  но часть данных выглядит `NaN`, часть числа:

```
df = df.replace(r'\s+','', regex=True)
df['Сумма'] = pd.to_numeric(y['Сумма'], errors='coerce')
df['Количество'] = pd.to_numeric(y['Количество'], errors='coerce')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста что я делаю не правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [decimal=','](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("333.csv", sep=';', header=0, index_col="СубконтоДт1", decimal=',')
```

Пробелы лучше удалить только в тех столбцах в которых они мешают:

```
df['Сумма'] = df['Сумма'].str.replace('\s', '')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Еще дописал вот эту строку и сработало. df.Сумма = df.Сумма.str.replace(',', '.').str.replace(' ', '')

Comment: @VladVladov, странно, о запятых должен был позаботиться параметр `pd.read_csv(..., decimal=',')`